# python: why does float's zero detection fail after calculating i as an exponent?

Tags: python, floating-point, complextype, exponent

```
0 == ((-1)**.5).real
```

... is False in python 3.5.1, whereas:

```
0 == complex(0,1).real
```

... is True. how are these two cases handled differently? when do the zero-detecting features of the float class work and when do they not?

Comment: `(-1)**0.5  -> (6.123233995736766e-17+1j)` on my machine, I'd assume because of [floating point math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> (-1)**0.5
(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)
```

That's all there is to it - due to floating-point vagaries, the real part of the computed result isn't exactly zero.  But in your other case it is:

```
>>> complex(0,1).real
0.0
```

By the way, `**` invokes a general-purpose exponentiation routine, which adds several layers of floating-point roundoff errors under the covers.  If you know you want a square root, it's better to use a square root function:

```
>>> import cmath
>>> cmath.sqrt(-1)
1j
```

Answer (score 2):

The fractional power is computed -- simplifying somewhat -- as **r cis theta**.  Since theta (pi) cannot be exactly represented as a binary fraction, the result is not *exactly* what you'd expect from hand calculation.  There are various "equal within a tolerance" functions you can apply to work around this.